# Mysql 5.1 to 5.5 error

Tags: mysql, linux

i upgrade mysqld 5.1.7 to 5.5.

And i have that error. i cant remove the mysql55w and install the other versions. i think it a bug...

I need help please, i open on ticket in web panel centos control, i upgrade with sh script (incorporate that cpanel)

```
    [root@ns3010965 yum.repos.d]# yum list installed | grep -i mysql
libmysqlclient16.x86_64         5.1.69-1.w6                        @webtatic
mysql-community-release.noarch  el6-5                              @/mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch
mysql55w-libs.x86_64            5.5.49-1.w6                        @webtatic
perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64           4.013-3.el6                        @base
php70w-mysql.x86_64             7.0.7-1.w6                         @webtatic

    [root@ns3010965 yum.repos.d]# yum install mysql
Complementos cargados:fastestmirror, replace
Configurando el proceso de instalación
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * extras: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * remi: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * remi-php56: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * remi-safe: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * rpmforge: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * updates: fr.mirror.babylon.network
El paquete mysql se hace obsoleto con mysql-community-client, en su lugar se está intentando instalar mysql-community-client-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64
Resolviendo dependencias
--> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.el6 will be instalado
--> Procesando dependencias: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) = 5.6.31-2.el6 para el paquete: mysql-community-client-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64
--> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.el6 will be instalado
--> Procesando dependencias: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.6.31-2.el6 para el paquete: mysql-community-libs-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64
--> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.6.31-2.el6 will be instalado
--> Resolución de dependencias finalizada

Dependencias resueltas

 Paquete                                                          Arquitectura                                     Versión                                                 Repositorio                                                 Tamaño

Instalando:
 mysql-community-client                                           x86_64                                           5.6.31-2.el6                                            mysql56-community                                            18 M
Instalando para las dependencias:
 mysql-community-common                                           x86_64                                           5.6.31-2.el6                                            mysql56-community                                           308 k
 mysql-community-libs                                             x86_64                                           5.6.31-2.el6                                            mysql56-community                                           1.9 M

Resumen de la transacción

Instalar       3 Paquete(s)

Tamaño total: 20 M
Tamaño instalado: 94 M
Está de acuerdo [s/N]:s
Descargando paquetes:
Ejecutando el rpm_check_debug
Ejecutando prueba de transacción


Error en la verificación de la transacción:
  file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1256.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1257.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp850.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp852.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp866.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/dec8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/geostd8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/greek.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hebrew.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/hp8.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/keybcs2.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8r.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/koi8u.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin1.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin2.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin5.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/latin7.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macce.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/macroman.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/swe7.xml from install of mysql-community-common-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18 from install of mysql-community-libs-5.6.31-2.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64

Resumen de errores


i cant remove that:

yum remove mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64 (said me that):



       [root@ns3010965 yum.repos.d]# yum remove mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
    Complementos cargados:fastestmirror, replace
    Configurando el proceso de eliminación
    Resolviendo dependencias
    --> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
    ---> Package mysql55w-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.49-1.w6 will be eliminado
    --> Procesando dependencias: mysql-libs para el paquete: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_7.1.x86_64
    --> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
    ---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.6.6-6.el6_7.1 will be eliminado
    --> Procesando dependencias: /usr/sbin/sendmail para el paquete: cronie-1.4.4-15.el6_7.1.x86_64
    --> Procesando dependencias: /usr/sbin/sendmail para el paquete: 14:arpwatch-2.1a15-16.el6.x86_64
    --> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
    ---> Package arpwatch.x86_64 14:2.1a15-16.el6 will be eliminado
    ---> Package cronie.x86_64 0:1.4.4-15.el6_7.1 will be eliminado
    --> Procesando dependencias: cronie = 1.4.4-15.el6_7.1 para el paquete: cronie-anacron-1.4.4-15.el6_7.1.x86_64
    --> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
    ---> Package cronie-anacron.x86_64 0:1.4.4-15.el6_7.1 will be eliminado
    --> Resolución de dependencias finalizada

    Dependencias resueltas

     Paquete                                                     Arquitectura                                        Versión                                                        Repositorio                                            Tamaño
    Eliminando:
     mysql55w-libs                                               x86_64                                              5.5.49-1.w6                                                    @webtatic                                              4.1 M
    Eliminando para las dependencias:
     arpwatch                                                    x86_64                                              14:2.1a15-16.el6                                               @base                                                  452 k
     cronie                                                      x86_64                                              1.4.4-15.el6_7.1                                               @updates                                               174 k
     cronie-anacron                                              x86_64                                              1.4.4-15.el6_7.1                                               @updates                                                43 k
     postfix                                                     x86_64                                              2:2.6.6-6.el6_7.1                                              @updates                                               9.7 M

    Resumen de la transacción

    Eliminar       5 Paquete(s)

    Tamaño instalado: 14 M
    Está de acuerdo [s/N]:s
    Descargando paquetes:
    Ejecutando el rpm_check_debug
    ERROR con el rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
    /etc/cron.d se necesita para (instalado) crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch
    Podría intentar ejecutar: rpm- Va --nofiles --nodigest
    Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
     yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx-2016-06-21-15-45bmKvsX.yumtx
    [root@ns3010965 yum.repos.d]# yum mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
    Complementos cargados:fastestmirror, replace
    No existe el comando: mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64. Por favor, utilice /usr/bin/yum --help
    [root@ns3010965 yum.repos.d]# yum remove mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64
    Complementos cargados:fastestmirror, replace
    Configurando el proceso de eliminación
    Resolviendo dependencias
    --> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
    ---> Package mysql55w-libs.x86_64 0:5.5.49-1.w6 will be eliminado
    --> Procesando dependencias: mysql-libs para el paquete: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_7.1.x86_64
    --> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
    ---> Package postfix.x86_64 2:2.6.6-6.el6_7.1 will be eliminado
    --> Procesando dependencias: /usr/sbin/sendmail para el paquete: cronie-1.4.4-15.el6_7.1.x86_64
    --> Procesando dependencias: /usr/sbin/sendmail para el paquete: 14:arpwatch-2.1a15-16.el6.x86_64
    --> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
    ---> Package arpwatch.x86_64 14:2.1a15-16.el6 will be eliminado
    ---> Package cronie.x86_64 0:1.4.4-15.el6_7.1 will be eliminado
    --> Procesando dependencias: cronie = 1.4.4-15.el6_7.1 para el paquete: cronie-anacron-1.4.4-15.el6_7.1.x86_64
    --> Ejecutando prueba de transacción
    ---> Package cronie-anacron.x86_64 0:1.4.4-15.el6_7.1 will be eliminado
    --> Resolución de dependencias finalizada

    Dependencias resueltas

     Paquete                                                     Arquitectura                                        Versión                                                        Repositorio                                            Tamaño

    Eliminando:
     mysql55w-libs                                               x86_64                                              5.5.49-1.w6                                                    @webtatic                                              4.1 M
    Eliminando para las dependencias:
     arpwatch                                                    x86_64                                              14:2.1a15-16.el6                                               @base                                                  452 k
     cronie                                                      x86_64                                              1.4.4-15.el6_7.1                                               @updates                                               174 k
     cronie-anacron                                              x86_64                                              1.4.4-15.el6_7.1                                               @updates                                                43 k
     postfix                                                     x86_64                                              2:2.6.6-6.el6_7.1                                              @updates                                               9.7 M

    Resumen de la transacción

    Eliminar       5 Paquete(s)

    Tamaño instalado: 14 M
    Está de acuerdo [s/N]:s
    Descargando paquetes:
    Ejecutando el rpm_check_debug
    ERROR con el rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
    /etc/cron.d se necesita para (instalado) crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch
    Podría intentar ejecutar: rpm- Va --nofiles --nodigest
    Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
     yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx-2016-06-21-20-503hetRP.yumtx
    [root@ns3010965 yum.repos.d]#
```

Comment: I would help if you could provide the english error message, or at least translate the relevant bits for us!

Comment: The first error says something along the lines of "Transaction verification error" with the charset list.  The second error basically translates to "You must have cron crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch".  Finally "This command doesn't exist:  mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64. Please use /usr/bin/yum --help"

Comment: @TimoSta  thx for help me. I have a error if i go to  yum remove mysql55w-libs-5.5.49-1.w6.x86_64 Eliminando:mysql55w-libs i cant remove for dependece...Ejecutando el rpm_check_debug ERROR con el rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:/etc/cron.d se necesita para (instalado) crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch http://i.imgur.com/6giebxE.png image for see

Comment: @T-Gray i posted the link. i have that error and i cant remove mysql for install i have conflict with http://i.imgur.com/Dj2oErL.png

Comment: @robbyq you might try the things in this post:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40179/remove-unused-packages

Comment: @TGray it ok, but now i install mysqld 5.6 and i go to start and said failed and after i go to see log and i have that. http://i.imgur.com/oR9p2UJ.png

Comment: You could try deleting ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 and then try to restart.  Other problems can be log directory permissions.  If you change the sizing on log files it can also cause similar issues.  Finally, trying to initialize the database on a box with insufficient memory can cause this.

Comment: @TGray i cant... havent mysql not work

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I don't know what "havent mysql not work" means.  You would delete the files and check the directories at the operating system level.